# How do I shift a column down as a new column in SQL?

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

How do I do this in SQL? Suppose I have a table that looks like this called `Logins`. This is just a snippet for `user_id` (the actual table will have much more users) where it shows the user's login timestamp and the occasions when they visited a website without logging in.

Logins:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       user_id       |       login_date    |      visit_date     |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-04-02 10:29:58 | 2017-04-02 10:10:41 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-04-02 12:49:35 | 2017-04-02 10:10:41 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-05-03 12:03:39 | 2017-04-02 10:10:41 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-05-03 12:03:39 | 2017-04-19 07:55:40 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-05-03 12:03:39 | 2017-05-03 11:54:11 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-06-02 10:30:04 | 2017-04-02 10:10:41 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-06-02 10:30:04 | 2017-04-19 07:55:40 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------+
```

How do I create this table?

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       user_id       |       login_date    |      visit_date     |      prev_login     |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-04-02 10:29:58 | 2017-04-02 10:10:41 |          NULL       |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-04-02 12:49:35 | 2017-04-02 10:10:41 | 2017-04-02 10:29:58 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-05-03 12:03:39 | 2017-04-02 10:10:41 | 2017-04-02 12:49:35 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-05-03 12:03:39 | 2017-04-19 07:55:40 | 2017-04-02 12:49:35 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-05-03 12:03:39 | 2017-05-03 11:54:11 | 2017-04-02 12:49:35 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-06-02 10:30:04 | 2017-04-02 10:10:41 | 2017-05-03 12:03:39 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|
|          12         | 2017-06-02 10:30:04 | 2017-04-19 07:55:40 | 2017-05-03 12:03:39 |
|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------|---------------------+
```

Basically, a new column that shows the previous login date, if there is none then have it be null. I tried using the lag function but it only looks back up to X previous rows and it would not work for my case. I tried doing a self-join but the number of rows exploded on me. Please help!

**Edit: nvm, finally solved it. Dense_rank with self join**

Comment: Possible duplicate. Use window function lag.

Comment: Right, `lag` will fit the bill. You don't have to look back at the x previous rows, only one previous row (when ordered by `login_date`).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe looking back only 1 previous row will not get me the desired output for the `prev_login`

Comment: You are right, and I think your solution is the best one.